# Extracting/Scaffolding models returned by stored procedure with entity framework core

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am in the process of creating a web app that has access to an existing database.

I am accessing the database with Entity Framework Core.

I have used `dotnet ef scaffold ...` to extract models for tables.

There are however some stored procedures in the database as well. How do I scaffold the return types of the stored procedures so that I can use the returned result from the stored procedure?

Is there perhaps a way to return anonymous types when calling the stored procedure?

Is there a command to generate the models for the return types?

Comment: You can use EF Core Power Tools!

Comment: We are not using visual studio. Is there a dotnet core tool that does this?

Comment: Yes, power tools include an (undocumented) command line tool.